# Is there a word for "damage done by fire" of a material?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

If a house had a wooden frame and was caught in a fire, there'd be nothing much left at the end. The damage would be huge. If a house had an iron frame and was caught in a fire, it probably wouldn't be too badly off at the end. Is there a scientific measure of "how things fare in a fire" please?

Comment: It does not seem to be about chemistry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not about chemistry.

Comment: 'Damage done by fire' is also found in  insurance parlance linked to insured loss claims. It is not even necessarily a direct fire loss, as could occur with an insurance policy (namely, a business interruption policy) covering loss of sales as a consequence of a covered fire event (for example, fires from illegal activities or civil unrest may NOT be  covered events).

Comment: It totally depends on the material.  Example , steel surface will oxidize but the nature of the oxide will depend on the time/temperature. The steel strength may be reduced or increased depending  on time/temperature and the original strength and composition.

Answer (score 1):

In English at least, there is no single word that captures this quality, for the simple reason that fire can affect materials in many different ways.

For example, an organic material may actually catch on fire itself and be combusted. "Combustibility" and "flammability" refer to slightly different descriptions of the tendency of materials to do this.

Metallic materials, on the other hand, may simply melt in the heat of the fire without combusting or may undergo microscopic structural changes due to the heat. The result can be a significant change in the properties of the material even after it has cooled back to ambient temperature, even though the material is not combustible. The effect is dependent on the temperature of the fire, which varies widely depending on fuel and conditions.

As a third example, a inflammable material that contains volatile components (like the water in a silica gel) might lose that volatile component in high heat, again permanently altering the properties of the material without combustion or melting.